# I just started Laravel and when creating a controller, the following problem occurs

Tags: php, laravel

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

No usages found in Project Files.-problem

Comment: As per the [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide, which you are encouraged to read before using the site, please don't post images of code, data or error messages. This information is text-based. Pasting it as graphics is very impractical as it can't be copied, searched, re-used in answers etc. It makes it difficult for those who might want to help you. Please [edit] your question to include the code as text and use the [formatting tools](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) to present it nicely, so that it is usable for those who want to help you. Thanks

Comment: See also [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Also, I edited out the non-English text, but please pay attention to the fact that [English is required for all content on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/non-english-questions). As you're new, please take the [tour] as well. Thankyou.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of pointing the route to the controller as a string, you can try accessing it like that.

```
use App\Http\Controllers\RomanController;
...
Route::get('/roman_age', [RomanController::class, 'age']);
```